# Regular expression for double square backers in objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex

I need to find a proper regular expression for words like `[[ "objective C" ]] , [[ "Java" ]]` ,and  `[[ "perl programming"]]` in Objective C

Tried with many combinations like

```
NSString *pattern1 = @"[\[][\[][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \",]+]]";

NSString *pattern2 = @"\[\[[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \",]+]]";
```

Apple documentation on `NSRegularExpression` Class says I need to use \ for treating next character as literal. Can some body help me to find what is the error in above regular expression ?

Comment: Can you make an `NSDictionary` and doing a `NSString rangeOfString` to search against each dictionary element ?

Comment: I need to find several occurrences of such pattern in a huge string. So I use [touchToWhat matchesInString:content options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])] where touchToWhat is a NSRegularExpression created from above pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is an escape character for  `NSString`, so you need to escape it.

`\[` in a regex, becomes `\\[` in `NSString`.

By the way a simpler regex for matching a single element is

```
\[\[ \"(\w|\s)+\" \]\]
```

which escaped for `NSString` is

```
@"\\[\\[ \\"(\\w|\\s)+\\" \\]\\]"
```

Comment: I think " does not need 2 \. Below worked for me

    NSString* secondPattern = @"\\[\\[\"(\\w|\\s)+\"\\]\\]";